# Storage of array in settings

Tags: settings-api

I'm creating a plugin that will store some simple layouts to be used in shortcodes.

The shortcode usage will be similar to `[shortcode layout="name"]`

With this mind I'll need to store each layout in the array as a key/value setup

Key = layout name

Value = layout markup

I'd like to store these in settings however I'm not sure how to go about it. How can I create a settings page that allows addition and editing. Normally my settings pages use code as follows and automatically wires into the api.

```
<input type="text" id="company_name" name="wpv_settings[company_name]" value="<?php echo $wpv_settings['company_name']; ?>" class="regular-text" />
```

However,  I can't find how to go about this when the setting is an array of key/values.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how this would be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the layout names are dynamic, perhaps it's better to store them in a numerically indexed nested array? Something like:

```
wpv_settings[layouts][0][name] = $key
wpv_settings[layouts][0][markup] = $value

wpv_settings[layouts][1][name] = $key
wpv_settings[layouts][1][markup] = $value
```

...etc?

Comment: Can I automate the creation/updating of the options for this using Wordpress settings register? <input type="text" id="company_name0" name="wpv_settings[layouts][0][name]" value="<?php echo $wpv_settings[layouts][0][name]; ?>" class="regular-text" />